# Slick Carousel does not load on initial page load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slick.js

I am using [slick carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) with ES6 and React.js and the carousel seems broken when the page first loads.

When I refresh everything falls into place. I can see in html when the carousel is broken, it is missing all slick carousel classes. Works every time when I reload. I'm not sure what needs to be done. Any ideas?

My javascript for carousel is:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import slick from 'slick-carousel'; 

const ImagesCarousel= {
  start() {
    $('.images-container').slick({
      dots: false,
      arrows: false,
      slidesToShow: 1.5,
      slidesToScroll: 2,
      autoplay: false,
      swipe: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 3000,
      infinite: false,
      mobileFirst: true,

      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 768,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            dots: false,
            arrows: true,
          }
        }
        ]
    });
  }
};

export default ImagesCarousel;
```

I am importing this in my main component and then starting the carousle as:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
   ProductImagesCarousel.start();
  }
```

and html is:

```
<div className="images">
              {
                this.props.imageUrl.map((url, index) => {
                  return <img src={url} key={index} />
                })
              }
</div>
```

imageUrl is pulled from object in props:

```
const productData = {
  productCode: "abc",
  imageUrl: [
    "./img/test1.jpg",
    "./img/test2.jpg",
    "./img/test3.jpg"
  ],
  name: "Test Product"
}
```

Comment: Code pls.. code...

Comment: As a first-level-supporter would say it... "There's no general error we know of. Please tell us EXACTLY what you've done." and exactly means: show us your code, and show us what you'Ve done so far trying to fix the problem, please.

Comment: Whole code is too long, I have updated my question with the key parts of the code related to the carousel.

Comment: Should you be initialising the carousel in `componentDIdMount()` and not `componentDidUpdate()`?

Comment: I have tried that too and only difference is if I use componentDIdMount(), images shows a thin lines instead. So both ways it is broken...with componenDidUpdate() images show as full size covering wide area of the page.

Comment: It is behaving as expected. The reason that it's not working as intended is that the DOM nodes are not completely rendered after `componentDidMount()` and as a result the slick function is acting on non-existent DOM nodes. The reason it would work on `componentDidUpdate()` is that the DOM nodes are already rendered, and when this life cycle method initialises, slick has a DOM to work on. I suggest you use the `react-slick` package then. Using jQuery and DOM manipulation with React is bound to cause issues.

Answer (score 3):

So seems like the issue was with the html markup. My images were not enclosed in divs. I don't see this being called out anywhere in the documentation, but I just wrapped the images in divs and it started working. Below is my new markup:

```
{ this.state.images.map((url, index) => { 
return <div className="thumbnail"><img src={url} key={index} /></div> 
})
}
```

Comment: This was driving me nuts! Thanks for surfacing